# Error: Cannot find module 'js' in Node Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a NodeJS express app which I am busy with.

After some development, I see this issue:

> Error: Cannot find module 'js'

After some Googling, I did not find any resolution. The usual resolution methods do not help:

1. ensure the module is available
2. remove all modules in `node_modules`, and reinstall them

What is strange is the Express app works out of the box, no changes, etc needed. Since the module [js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js) (*I assume*) is missing *somehow*, I added this to my dependancy list:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "js": "^0.1.0",                  <------------I added this
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "ws": "^7.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "^8.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "solc": "0.5.8",
    "scrypt": "^6.0.3",
    "python2": "^0.0.1",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.37"

  }
}
```

How do I get this problem?

**Steps:**

- I run the app in debug mode (Webstorm), and wait for that app to initialize. (no errors)

**Console Output**

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38687/75fc3e83-8a03-46ff-b769-b49dc880e767
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
  commerce-chain-gui:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
```

- Browse to `http://localhost:3000` (*where it is hosted*): page has errors.

**Console Output (appended)**

```
GET / 500 2736.227 ms - 3474
```

**Stacktrace** (shown in webpage)

```
Cannot find module 'js'
Error: Cannot find module 'js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at new View (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/routes/index.js:6:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/mnt/win_c/Users/s2134/IdeaProjects/commerce-chain-gui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

How can I resolve this?

**Update**

I created a new Express app, copied over everything in pieces to possibly find the culprit...

The app works (in the new express app), but I did not find out what caused the problem.

**This is still an issue, as no solution has yet been found**

Comment: try remove ^ . ---> "js": "^0.1.0",

Comment: @ORBIT sorry, I dont think I was clear. Initially it was not there, and it did not work. Hence, a missing module, I added it and it still did not work. I will remove it nontheless.

Comment: @ORBIT removed it (and you guess it, no luck)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install it globally
`npm i -g js`
and then you can use it in the console.

From the link you send : `js is a a better alternative to node -p` and node -p is used in system terminal [to print the result of a script](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script)

UPDATE : did you correctly register your view engine ? in the stacktace you give, you can see :

`at new View ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)`

when looking the code in this file there is :

```
    if (!opts.engines[this.ext]) {
      // load engine
      var mod = this.ext.substr(1)
      debug('require "%s"', mod) // Here is a debug function

      // default engine export
      var fn = require(mod).__express // Here is your error

      if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
          throw new Error('Module "' + mod + '" does not provide a view engine.')
      }

      opts.engines[this.ext] = fn
    }
```

you can view express debug by launching your app with `DEBUG=express:* node index.js`

UPDATE 2 : it seems that your are trying to load a view with the `.js` extension : express use the extension to find the view engine => for exemple, the file `file.pug` will be render with the pug engine

Comment: I am not sure if that will solve the problem. I had just created a new test Express app and it renders fine. It is just this app (I am inquiring about) that is causing the problem. I cannot be a missing module (in that sense)

Comment: so, why did you added the js module ? what was the previous error ?

Comment: there is only 1 error. the Cannot find module 'js' error. I added the 'js' module dependancy as it is the logical thing to do when a missing module message appears. After adding the 'js' module dependancy, the *same* error persists. I had removed the 'js' module dependancy and the *same* error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. Despite this, I have a little more information.

The problem appeared when I tried to transfer my old page to the nodejs express engine using view engine ejs. As it turned out, the engine for some reason tolerates some javascript files of the site as files to be repaired.

A lot should explain this log dump:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ico'
Require stack:
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/index.js
- /root/bot/core.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at new View (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at ressend (/root/bot/include/routes/index.js:27:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  express:router dispatching GET /server/js/bootstrap.min.js +13ms
  express:router query  : /server/js/bootstrap.min.js +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /server/js/bootstrap.min.js +0ms
  express:router session  : /server/js/bootstrap.min.js +0ms
  express:view require "js" +0ms

Error: Cannot find module 'js'
Require stack:
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /root/bot/node_modules/express/index.js
- /root/bot/core.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at new View (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at ressend (/root/bot/include/routes/index.js:27:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  express:router dispatching GET /server/js/demo/widgets.js +3ms
  express:router query  : /server/js/demo/widgets.js +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /server/js/demo/widgets.js +0ms
  express:router session  : /server/js/demo/widgets.js +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /server/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js +1ms
  express:router query  : /server/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /server/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js +0ms
  express:router session  : /server/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js +0ms
  express:view require "js" +0ms
  express:view require "js" +1ms
  express:router dispatching GET /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.min.js +5ms
  express:router query  : /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.min.js +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.min.js +0ms
  express:router session  : /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.min.js +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /server/js/demo/nifty-demo.min.js +0ms
  express:router query  : /server/js/demo/nifty-demo.min.js +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /server/js/demo/nifty-demo.min.js +0ms
  express:router session  : /server/js/demo/nifty-demo.min.js +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js +0ms
  express:router query  : /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js +0ms
  express:router session  : /server/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js +0ms
(...)
```

FIX:
The problem results from incorrect paths to static files.
Step 1:
Add all static catalogs with example:

```
config.www.static_directories.forEach((dir)=>{
  app.use('/'+dir, express.static(path.join(config.www.directory+dir)))
})
```

or

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Step: 2
Correct all paths to static files so that they refer to the root directory, e.g.
`<script src="/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though, if you want to extend on the question just make another and reference this question in it.

Comment: I edited the content because it didn't stick all the way. This is the question and answer how to solve it. I hope that the solution to my problem (which I presented) will also turn out to be a solution to a colleague's problem. A colleague of what I understood does not need the JS module for anything. The error is fairly poorly described, and debugging takes some time.